# accountsWithAccountType return empty array

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I was following [CS193P](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) and trying to replicate from screencasts. In one screencast, there's example of fetching twitter API and show it as tableView. But when I tried it, accountsWithAccountType return empty array. As a result, it lead to `else` condition and it show me as  `Couldn't discover Twitter account type`.  My Code is as follows

```
let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
        accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(twitterAccountType, options: nil) { (granted, _) in

            if granted {
                //  test is empty array 
                let test = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(twitterAccountType)
                println(test)
                if let account = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(twitterAccountType)?.last as? ACAccount {
                    twitterAccount = account
                    self.performTwitterRequest(request, handler: handler)
                } else {
                    let error = "Couldn't discover Twitter account type."
                    self.log(error)
                    handler(error)
                }
            } else {
                let error = "Access to Twitter was not granted."
                self.log(error)
                handler(error)
            }
        }
```

When I tried to print `twitterAccountType`, it show `Twitter (com.apple.twitter)`. By the ways, I also download working version of it from that link and tried it. It still show the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you don't have a twitter account in the Setting.

Go to Setting > Twitter > Login with your twitter ID

and then try again.

I tested on device and simulator. It's working find after adding twitter account.

Comment: I dont see any twitter in the settings. Where can I find it?